# How to create a integer array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried list

```
new=[]
new=input()
print(new)
```

gives me a string as default. How to find the second largest integer from that? I have tried other answers that was found in this site but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Can we see what the input string is? Give us some input and output examples...

Comment: input: 1 2 3 4 5                 output: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not compare strings when you want to compare integers! you need to convert those strings to integers:

```
in_str = '243 3443 6543 43 546'
ints = [int(i) for i in in_str.split()]
ints.sort(reverse=True)
print(ints[1])  # 3443
```

(`'9' > '10'` is `True` when comparing strings).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
new = []
new = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
new.sort()
print(new[-2])
```

It assumes that your input values are separeted by ' '. For example:

```
6 5 4 3 7 8
```

`map()` maps your strings into integers, which returns map-object. Then you can invoke a `list()` on it to get a list. After sorting you can get penultimate element by accessing `[-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the heapq module and map, change to ints first then get the second largest;

```
new = heapq.nlargest(2, map(int, new))
```